# Compare first & last name (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have first name and last name in database and same fields, coming from Dto

I need to check if those fields is differs

I wrote code like this

`client.*` - values from database

`input.*` -  values from DTO

```
var isNameChanged = (client.FirstName + client.LastName).ToLower().Replace(" ","") == (input.FirstName+input.LastName).ToLower().Replace(" ","");
```

Any suggestion on how I can beautify this code?

Comment: For starters, never use `ToLower`, just do a case insensitive comparison.   Why is removing spaces valid?  Why not just search your database for the right first name, last name?

Comment: This code doesn't work anyway, you need to check first and last name separately. For example, if it went from `1234` and `5678` to `123` and `45678`

Comment: fields can be with spaces @Neil

Comment: @Neil Why is `ToLower` a bad idea? Is it a performance problem?

Comment: @ibram It produces issues with different cultures. Also it creates new strings which are not needed. Better to use `string.Compare` with `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`

Answer (score 2):

Add this method somewhere

```
static bool CompareNameField(string data, string input) {
    return data.Trim().Equals(input.Trim(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
}
```

Change your comparison code to this

```
bool isNameChanged = true;

if (
    CompareNameField(client.FirstName, input.FirstName) &&
    CompareNameField(client.LastName, input.LastName)
    )
{
    isNameChanged = false;
}
```

Why?

- It's easy to read. It's clear without a measure of a doubt what you're doing at even a first glance of the code and simple to understand.
- It doesn't repeat code unnecessarily. By extracting the process of both cleaning the fields for comparison and the comparison itself you are not unnecessarily copying code. This feeds into "It's easy to read".
- It's extensible. What if you need to add a 'MiddleName' field at some point? Easy to simply add a new `&& CompareNameField` to the `if` statement without both unnecessarily copying code and sacrificing readability further.
- It's not broken. You cannot concatenate two fields together and compare them like this, you have lost the fact that there is *two distinct values*. Concatenating the fields `abc` + `def` and comparing it to `ab` + `cdef` will determine that they're the same thing because, in a way, the metadata of them existing as two distinct fields has been removed.
- It's not broken (again). You were removing all spaces from the fields instead of what I assume was supposed to be trimming spaces from the start and ends of fields. Names are funny and they can sometimes contain thing you don't expect like dashes, two last names, and a whole host of other things; there may very well be names out there that contain spaces and it would suck for them if they accidentally set their last name to `ab cdef`, then try and fix it by changing it to `abc def` or `abcdef` only for the program to tell them they're the same thing.
- It's not dependent on one culture. Languages, like names, like to do a lot of things you never expect; capitalization rules and dotless characters for example. Best to use `StringComparison.InvariantCulture` and `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` to compare two inputs of variable cultures. [ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/compare-strings#linguistic-comparisons)